# Matlab applying an FIR filter to a signal, generated in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, finite-impulse-response

I want to create an FIR in Matlab and apply it to a signal (also generated in Matlab). You will find the code below. I will put my questions in order from here.

1) The filter coefficients vector "b" should contain coefficients for a bandpass with a filter order of 100 and a passband of 1000Hz to 2000Hz. My sampling frequency is 50.000Hz. Matlab uses normalized frequency. As far as I have understood, my formula to transform my frequency to a normalized frequency is f_norm = (2*f)/f_sample. So in my example I would get 0.04 for 1000Hz and 0.08 for 2000Hz. Is that correct?

2)I am creating a test signal sinuses with the frequency 200Hz, 2500Hz and 5500Hz and compute the two sided fft of the amplitude. The graph is attached[image: FFT signal]

This looks good, since the overall amplitude should be about 0.33 for every signal part. Now, when I apply my filter to the signal and plot the two sided fft of the result, it shows the next graphFFT Signal after filter [image: FFT after filter]

I mean I can see the 5500Hz being filtered out, but the amplitude of the 2500Hz signal drops by a factor of 10 and the 200Hz signal is also not filtered out completely. What are some things that I can improve here? 3) Also, when I only raise the filter order, I am getting worse results with more suppression on the 2500Hz signal and less suppression on the signals that I want to have filtered out.

```
%fs = 50000
b = fir1(100, [0.04 0.08], 'bandpass');    %passband 1000Hz bis 2000Hz
figure(1);
freqz(b,1,2001);

f1 = 100;                  %Hz
f2 = 5500;
f3 = 2500;
A = 1.00;                  %Amplitude
sampleRate = 50000;
sampleTime = (1/sampleRate);
t = 0:sampleTime:1;

s1 = A/3 * sin(2 * pi * f1 * t);
s2 = A/3 * sin(2 * pi * f2 * t);
s3 = A/3 * sin(2 * pi * f3 * t);

signal = s1 + s2 + s3;

Y = abs(fft(signal));
samplePoints = length(Y);
Y = Y / samplePoints;
F = linspace(0,50000,50001);

figure(2);
plot(F,Y);
grid on;

y = filter(b,1,signal);

Y = abs(fft(y));
samplePoints = length(Y);
Y = Y / samplePoints;
F = linspace(0,50000,50001);

figure(3);
plot(F,Y);
grid on;
```

Comment: Why are you surprised that your 2.5kHz signal is attenuated when your filter is designed for the range from 1kHz-2kHz? I recommend you to plot your results in dB which allows you to see more details.

Comment: ...sorry guys, you can't possibly imagine how stupid I feel like now. Somehow my brain managed to convert the range to 1kHz to 3kHz and I always wondered why the 2,5kHz becomes attenuated.... Today is just not my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your result match expectations, I don't see anything in there that's unusual or unexpected.

Filter design is a complicated trade off between complexity/cost, stopband attenuation, pass band ripple, transition steepness, phase distortion, time domain ringing, non-causality, latency, etc. The best way to go about is to clearly articulate the requirements for your specific application and then evaluate any design against these requirements line-by-line.

I'd also be careful with spectral analysis: direct FFT works sometimes, but something like pwelch() is typically much more robust.

Comment: I already gave the answer in a comment above, I just feel so stupid right now... but thank you for your hint at pwelch(), I didn't know about that

Comment: I exchanged the 2,5kHz with 1,5kHz and it works as intended.... But now that I detected this forum, I'll be sure to have some more questions : )